# Visual Studio Team Services and Xamarin.Android/iOS build configuration

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to add continues build for my Xamarin forms project which has Android and iOS project in it. I also have Team Services account. I host my code in external Git repository. I configured external git in Team Services project as well. Now I want to create build definitions for Xamarin iOS/Android, but cannot find any good article which explains it in detail. I don't know how I configure options shown in this image.

[image]

Can anyone help me get this configured correctly.

Comment: What is the detailed issue you have?